Blue-screen error
I use Windows 11 Enterprise, and these days, I get the blue screen error two or three times a day regardless of what I'm doing. It doesn't matter if I'm playing a game or just surfing the web; it still might happen.
Stop Code: DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

and the arguments are as follows
0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000501
0x0000000000000500
0xFFFFF8025591D340

I also have to add that my pc doesn't generate minidump files so I can't provide it. I tried to fix the issue but I had no success.
How can I resolve this?

For games, likely due to anti-cheat software: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problem-with-dpc-watchdog-violation-windows-11/7aff4138-8b02-4a26-82b0-a6b82bf364a3 . That post suggests turning off kernel isolation in Defender (for Endpoint). Could also be a hardware issue: https://www.lifewire.com/fix-dpc-watchdog-violation-windows-11-6503496

@DrMoishePippik I turned off kernel isolation, and it seems to have worked wonders. I haven't had any blue screens since. Thank you so much!
